# How to check 6 consecutive days from specified date?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am stuck in mid of my work, that how can i check for consecutive 6 days ?

**for example :**

if specified date is : 01/01/2011

And i wanted to check for 6 consecutive days from 01/01/2011 from the list of dates available.
after finding consecutive day, it should continue with next consecutive chain ahead which is available in the list.

and track how many time 6 consecutive days is find and when ?

if any one can help me,it will be very helpful to me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,Jon SkeetYour understanding is some what different But i want to check for 6 consecutive days that if user is present for all six consecutive days and also on 7th day then 7th day will be considered as overtime and so on while enries exis in list of available dates.

Comment: Please edit your question to give sample input and desired output. That will make it a lot easier to help you. For example, it will make a difference if the input is known to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list of dates and then use your logic

```
 List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    //add your dates here
    Collections.sort(dateList);
    int count = 0;
    Date previousDate = null;
    List<Date> datesGroup = new ArrayList<Date>();
    for (Date date : dateList) {
        if (previousDate == null) {
            previousDate = new Date();
            count++;
        } else {
            long diff = date.getTime() - previousDate.getTime();
            if (diff == 86400000) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
                datesGroup.clear();
            }
        }
        datesGroup.add(date);
        previousDate.setTime(date.getTime());
        if (count == 6) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (Date dates : datesGroup) {
        System.out.println("dates sorted : " + dates);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, it's not clear what you're really after - but it's almost *certain* that using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) will make your life easier than the standard library. It's simply a better date/time API which leads to clearer code.

For example, this will iterate over a date and the 6 dates following it:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2010, 1, 1); // January is 1 in Joda. How novel.
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    // Do something with date here - check it or whatever
    date = date.plusDays(1);
}
```

You could also write this in a slightly different way:

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2010, 1, 1);
LocalDate end = start.plusDays(7);
for (LocalDate date = start; date.isBefore(end); date = date.plusDays(1))
{
    // Do something with date here
}
```

Comment: `i < 7;` !! , shouldn't it be `i < 6;`

Comment: @org.life.java: Not after I've moved my comment. It depends whether the OP wants to check "the current date and the subsequence 6 days" (i.e. 7 days in total) or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar lowerCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        lowerCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        lowerCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        lowerCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
        //set other param 0

        Calendar higherCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        higherCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        higherCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        higherCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
        higherCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        //set other param 0
        Calendar calToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (calToCheck.compareTo(higherCal) <= 0   &&  calToCheck.compareTo(lowerCal) >= 0 ){
                //YES
        }
```

**Also See**

- [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code gives you the difference between two dates in days:

```
import java.util.*;
 public class DateDifference {
   public static void main(String args[]){
     DateDifference difference = new DateDifference();
     }
     DateDifference() {
     Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
     Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();

     cal1.set(2008, 8, 1); 
     cal2.set(2008, 9, 31);
     System.out.println("Days= "+daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime()));
     }
     public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
     return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
         }
   }
```

You should have no problem in incorporating it into your code so that it does what you need. The code has been taken from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/number-days-between.shtml).